# Finding the cos of an angle in java

Tags: java

I was asked to find the cos following this equation:

I was able to find the sin of the angle, however when finding the cos, the number I would get is quite different from the correct value:

I used the following code for finding the cos.
ps: I can't use math.cos

[image: cosine expression]

```
public static double cos(double x, int n){

    // declaring cos and factorial

    double cos = 0.0;


    // this loop determines how long does the loop go so the answer is more accurate
    for (long howlong = 1 ; howlong <=n; howlong++){
        double factorial =1;

    // this will calculate the factorial for even numbers ex/ 2*2 = 4 , 4-2 = 2
    // for the denominator 

    for (int factorialnumber=1; factorialnumber<=2*howlong-2; factorialnumber++){
        factorial = factorial * howlong;    

    }

    // now we need to create the pattern for the + and -
    // so we use % that switches the sign everytime i increments by 1

    if (howlong%2==1){
        cos = cos + (double) (Math.pow(x, 2*howlong-2)/factorial);
    }

    else{
        cos = cos - (double) (Math.pow(x, 2*howlong-2)/factorial);
    }
    }
    return cos;
}
```

edit: I figured out my mistake as it was multiplying the factorial by how long instead of factorial number.

Comment: We don't know what your input, expected output or actual output is, making it harder to help you. (It could easily be a degrees vs radians issue, for example.)

Comment: You'll lose precision by using a `double` for your factorial.

Comment: sorry i deleted it by mkstake, i added it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two bugs.

**(Bug 1)** Where you wrote

```
factorial = factorial * howlong;
```

it should have been

```
factorial = factorial * factorialnumber;
```

**(Bug 2)** You're not resetting your factorials on each iteration through the outer loop.  So you need to move the line

```
double factorial =1;
```

down a couple of lines, so that it's inside the outer loop.

If you make those two changes, then the result of `cos(Math.PI / 6, 10)` is `0.8660254037844386` which seems correct to me.

Comment: thank you so much it seems to work without moving the factorial.

Comment: but where should i move it, out of which loop?

Comment: Exactly as I said.  Move `double factorial =1;` so it's just down inside the outer loop.  You have to do this, otherwise your answer is `0.8644874260241855`, which is _close_, but wrong.

Comment: it works perfectly after moving the factorial, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The computation of your factorial was wrong.
Try it with this code:

```
public static double cos(double x, int n) {

    // declaring cos and factorial

    double cos = 0.0;


    // this loop determines how long does the loop go so the answer is more
    // accurate
    for (long howlong = 1; howlong <= n; howlong++) {

        // now we need to create the pattern for the + and -
        // so we use % that switches the sign everytime i increments by 1

        if (howlong % 2 == 1) {
            cos = cos + Math.pow(x, 2 * howlong - 2) / factorial(2 * howlong - 2);
        }

        else {
            cos = cos - Math.pow(x, 2 * howlong - 2) / factorial(2 * howlong - 2);
        }
    }
    return cos;
}

public static long factorial(long n) {
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        result *= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: P.S.: I tested it :-)

Comment: Yes, this answer is correct.  There's nearly always more than one way of doing these things.

Answer (score -1):

Your calculation is not correct, please change to

```
 double value = 1;
            for (int factorialnumber = 1; factorialnumber <= 2 * howlong - 2; factorialnumber++) {
                value = factorialnumber * value;
            }

            factorial = value;
            System.out.println(value + " " + (2 * howlong - 2));
```

Comment: @DavidWallace I have 0.8998780704734082, which is pretty close

Comment: No, it's not pretty close.  10 terms should be enough to get you within the precision of a double-precision number to the true cosine, which is `sqrt(3) / 2` or  `0.8660254037844386`.  You are off by over 3% (roughly half as much as OP's original program), so your algorithm is wrong.

Comment: could you please put SOP just after factorial calculation? Are you actually calculating factorial of 2, 4, 6 (even numbers)? Why would you say that 10 should be enough? usually, you have to calculate the difference between amount(i) and amount(i+1), if they less than the given error threshold, then we should stop. But not the number of iterations, as the sequence may not not approach.

Comment: Yes, but the tenth term _is_ the difference between your `amount(i)` and `amount(i+1)`.  And this tenth term is `(pi/6)^18 / 18!` which is about `3 x 10^-70` - that is, it's much smaller than one ULP for a number of this size.  So this is sufficient accuracy - there may still be a loss of precision caused by rounding errors in the individual additions and subtractions, but you're not going to fix this by including more terms.

Comment: @DavidWallace Let me check again and I shall post the answer.